# MacOS Catalina: How to move the pictures folder to an external drive

Tags: catalina, external-disk, folders

How can I move my Pictures folder (users/me/Pictures) to an external flash drive (volumes/"SD UltraFit 256GB (Fotos)") using MacOS Catalina and "link" the new folder back to its original destination. Symlinks don't seem to work here with OsX 10.15.

Comment: Are you moving the system library or leaving that on the main drive? https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204414 You can have multiple libraries with Photos.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how to answer that. I used to have the Pictures folder on my external drive. The "Fotos Mediathek.photoslibrary" was part of that (volumes/"SD UltraFit 256GB (Fotos)"/Bilder/Fotos Mediathek.photoslibrary. After the symlink broke I renamed the old Pictures folder on the external flash drive so that I could try to fix things with a new empty Pictures folder on that drive and then copy back its old content. So I think the short answer is yes.

Comment: Just to clarify. In the German MacOS versions the Pictures folder externally should show as "Bilder". The one that was recreated by the system (users/me/Pictures) presents itself as Pictures internally and externally.